# ansible remote server name (jenkins slave node) in the ansible host file

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, ansible-inventory

I am not sure how to specify my host name in ansible host file. I am not able to ping my remote machine because of this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

jenkins slave node name: agent007

Comment: Hi, please don't post code as images. Use code blocks instead.

Comment: Okay apologies..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In /etc/ansible/hosts list the host machines:
   [localhost]
   IP address of local host
2. u should have passwordless connection using ssh-keygen -t rsa which will give u a rsa.pubkey which should be copied on authorization keys of host machine
3. then u can run the playbook

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have mapped the local DNS if you are trying to ping using hostname.
Or else try Ip. Also you should make the password-less authentication for this.
Use ssh-keygen and copy the pub key to the remote server in authorized hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

The remote host you are trying to reach needs to be defined in your ansible inventory file, usually named `hosts`:

```
agent007 ansible_ssh_host=<ip addr>
```

Then you can explicitly use this inventory file with the `-i` option

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts firstplaybook.yml
```